# Resetting Wasm memory in node.js

Tags: node.js, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have a Wasm module (compiled with Rust/wasm-pack) that I am running in node.js. The module works under normal conditions, but given certain input data it can run out of memory. I would like to continue to process subsequent data sets with the same Wasm module, but after the first OOM error, the module no longer works (throws exception regardless of input data).

I have tried doing a fresh `require()` before each usage of the module , including clearing  `require.cache`, but the module still fails to run.

Is there some sort of global memory space for Wasm modules that needs to be reset, or some method for re-`require`-ing modules that I'm missing?

Comment: If you could provide at least some details on the way you use the module, then it might give us a clue what's going on:
- How do you load the module into your node app?
- What allocator do you use?
- Have you implemented any custom memory management (aside from the shim generated by wasm-pack)?

Cheers!